# Vectorize short to float conversion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vectorization

I am trying to understand why Visual Studio 2012 (x64) doesn't want to vectorized a conversion from a `short` to a `float`. Does anybody have a reason or a way around?

```
//unsigned short* __restrict A,B,C,D    
for (int j = 0; j < H*W;j++) 
{
    float Gs = D[j]-B[j];
    float Gc = A[j]-C[j];
    in[j]=atan2f(Gs,Gc);
}
```

> info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1101'

**RESOLUTION**

Runtime using shorts and not vectorizing is about `800ms`

Runtime converting to all ints and auto vectorizing is about `140ms` (!!!)

Comment: One way is to use SSE4.1 to convert `short` -> `int`. Then use the `int` -> `float` conversion intrinsic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/05/22/auto-vectorizer-in-visual-studio-11-did-it-work.aspx), it appears that your "Loop contains a non-vectorizable conversion operation (may be implicit)". Have you tried first converting to a type which is the same width as a `float` (such as `int`)?

For a more concrete reason, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161807/sse-convert-short-integer-to-float). Apparently, there is no direct way in SSE to convert an SSE register consisting of a vector of shorts to a vector of floats, however there is an instruction that converts 32-bit integers to floats.

Comment: Using an intermediate such as `int foo = D[j]-B[j]` doesn't seem to help it along. I guess I may need to change all my shorts to floats.

Comment: You should cast to ints before the subtraction, not after. That way the subtraction itself can be written as a vector operation on ints, and then be vectorized. Also, you shouldn't need to change all your shorts to floats; just change them to ints.