# is there an equivalent for _mm_loadu_ps for char *?

Tags: c++, sse

What I'm trying to do is to load four char values and add them to a vector of 4 floats. at first what I did was something like that:

```
// char b[1024] is defined somewhere else
__declspec(align(16)) float d[3];
__declspec(align(16)) float a[4];
__m128* pSrcDst1 = (__m128*) d;
__m128* pSrc2 = (__m128*) a;

a[0] = b[i  ];
a[1] = b[i+1];
a[2] = b[i+2];
a[3] = b[i+3];

*pSrcDst1 = _mm_add_ps(*pSrcDst1, *pSrc2);
```

I wanted to take advantage of something like `_mm_loadu_ps` for `char*` so I could do:

```
// char b[1024] is defined somewhere else
__declspec(align(16)) float d[3];
__declspec(align(16)) float a[4];
__declspec(align(16)) char c[4];
__m128* pSrcDst1 = (__m128*) d;
__m128* pSrc2 = (__m128*) a;
__m64* pSrc3 = (__m64*) c;

*pSrc3 = _mm_loadu_ps(&b[i]);
*pSrc2 = _mm_cvtpu8_ps(*pSrc3);
*pSrcDst1 = _mm_add_ps(*pSrcDst1, *pSrc2);
```

What is the right & optimized way of doing this?

Comment: What does it mean to add a char to a float, for you?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - sorry for not making it clear - it's 8 bit unsigned int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you first need to expand your uint8_t values to uint32_t values, then you can load them and do any operations you like.  For details, see here: [SSE: convert short integer to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161807/sse-convert-short-integer-to-float)