# Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I am optimizing an algorithm for Gaussian blur on an image and I want to replace the usage of a float buffer[8] in the code below with an __m256 intrinsic variable. What series of instructions is best suited for this task?

```
// unsigned char *new_image is loaded with data
...
  float buffer[8];

  buffer[x ]      = new_image[x];       
  buffer[x + 1] = new_image[x + 1]; 
  buffer[x + 2] = new_image[x + 2]; 
  buffer[x + 3] = new_image[x + 3]; 
  buffer[x + 4] = new_image[x + 4]; 
  buffer[x + 5] = new_image[x + 5]; 
  buffer[x + 6] = new_image[x + 6]; 
  buffer[x + 7] = new_image[x + 7]; 
 // buffer is then used for further operations
...

//What I want instead in pseudocode:
 __m256 b = [float(new_image[x+7]), float(new_image[x+6]), ... , float(new_image[x])];
```

Comment: Have you checked optimized assembly? You compiler might already do this for you.

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284106/scaling-byte-pixel-values-y-axb-with-sse2-as-floats.  That one is broader, and asks about a specific processing task, but my answer there covers unpacking to floats and back (for SSE, not AVX).  The16bit fixed-point suggestion is relevant here too, if you can use it instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using AVX2, you can use PMOVZX to zero-extend your chars into 32-bit integers in a 256b register.  From there, conversion to float can happen in-place.

```
; rsi = new_image
VPMOVZXBD   ymm0,  [rsi]   ; or SX to sign-extend  (Byte to DWord)
VCVTDQ2PS   ymm0, ymm0     ; convert to packed foat
```

This is a good strategy even if you want to do this for multiple vectors, but even better might be **a 128-bit broadcast load to feed `vpmovzxbd ymm,xmm` and `vpshufb ymm` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`) for the high 64 bits,** because Intel SnB-family CPUs don't micro-fuse a `vpmovzx ymm,mem`, only only `vpmovzx xmm,mem`.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).  Broadcast loads are single uop with no ALU port required, running purely in a load port.  So this is 3 total uops to bcast-load + vpmovzx + vpshufb.

(TODO: write an intrinsics version of that.  It also sidesteps the problem of missed optimizations for `_mm_loadl_epi64` -> `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`.)

Of course this requires a shuffle control vector in another register, so it's only worth it if you can use that multiple times.

`vpshufb` is usable because the data needed for each lane is there from the broadcast, and the high bit of the shuffle-control will zero the corresponding element.

This broadcast + shuffle strategy might be good on Ryzen; Agner Fog doesn't list uop counts for `vpmovsx/zx ymm` on it.

---

Do **not** do something like a 128-bit or 256-bit load and then shuffle that to feed further `vpmovzx` instructions.  Total shuffle throughput will probably already be a bottleneck because `vpmovzx` is a shuffle.  Intel Haswell/Skylake (the most common AVX2 uarches) have 1-per-clock shuffles but 2-per-clock loads.  Using extra shuffle instructions instead of folding separate memory operands into `vpmovzxbd` is terrible.  Only if you can *reduce* total uop count like I suggested with broadcast-load + vpmovzxbd + vpshufb is it a win.

---

My answer on [Scaling byte pixel values (y=ax+b) with SSE2 (as floats)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284106/scaling-byte-pixel-values-y-axb-with-sse2-as-floats/32288984#32288984) may be relevant for converting back to `uint8_t`.  The pack-back-to-bytes afterward part is semi-tricky if doing it with AVX2 `packssdw/packuswb`, because they work in-lane, unlike `vpmovzx`.

---

**With only AVX1, not AVX2**, you should do:

```
VPMOVZXBD   xmm0,  [rsi]
VPMOVZXBD   xmm1,  [rsi+4]
VINSERTF128 ymm0, ymm0, xmm1, 1   ; put the 2nd load of data into the high128 of ymm0
VCVTDQ2PS   ymm0, ymm0     ; convert to packed float.  Yes, works without AVX2
```

You of course never need an array of float, just `__m256` vectors.

---

**GCC / MSVC missed optimizations for `VPMOVZXBD ymm,[mem]` with intrinsics**

GCC and MSVC are bad at folding a `_mm_loadl_epi64` into a memory operand for `vpmovzx*`.  (But at least there *is* a load intrinsic of the right width, unlike for `pmovzxbq xmm, word [mem]`.)

We get a `vmovq` load and then a separate `vpmovzx` with an XMM input.  (With ICC and clang3.6+ we get safe + optimal code from using `_mm_loadl_epi64`, like from gcc9+)

But gcc8.3 and earlier *can* fold a `_mm_loadu_si128` 16-byte load intrinsic into an 8-byte memory operand.  This gives optimal asm at `-O3` on GCC, but is unsafe at `-O0` where it compiles to an actual `vmovdqu` load that touches more data that we actually load, and could go off the end of a page.

Two gcc bugs submitted because of this answer:

- [SSE/AVX movq load (_mm_cvtsi64_si128) not being folded into pmovzx](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68923)  (**fixed for gcc9**, but the fix breaks load folding for a 128-bit load so the workaround hack for old GCC makes gcc9 do worse.)
- [No intrinsic for x86 `MOVQ m64, %xmm` in 32bit mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68924).  (TODO: report this for clang/LLVM as well?)

---

There's no intrinsic to use SSE4.1 `pmovsx` / `pmovzx` as a load, only with a `__m128i` source operand.  But the asm instructions only read the amount of data they actually use, not a 16-byte `__m128i` memory source operand.  Unlike `punpck*`, you can use this on the last 8B of a page without faulting.  (And on unaligned addresses even with the non-AVX version).

So here's the evil solution I've come up with.  Don't use this, `#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__` is Bad, making it possible to create bugs that only happen in the debug build or only in the optimized build!

```
#if !defined(__OPTIMIZE__)
// Making your code compile differently with/without optimization is a TERRIBLE idea
// great way to create Heisenbugs that disappear when you try to debug them.
// Even if you *plan* to always use -Og for debugging, instead of -O0, this is still evil
#define USE_MOVQ
#endif

__m256 load_bytes_to_m256(uint8_t *p)
{
#ifdef  USE_MOVQ  // compiles to an actual movq then movzx ymm, xmm with gcc8.3 -O3
    __m128i small_load = _mm_loadl_epi64( (const __m128i*)p);
#else  // USE_LOADU // compiles to a 128b load with gcc -O0, potentially segfaulting
    __m128i small_load = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*)p );
#endif

    __m256i intvec = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32( small_load );
    //__m256i intvec = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32( *(__m128i*)p );  // compiles to an aligned load with -O0
    return _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(intvec);
}
```

With USE_MOVQ enabled, [`gcc -O3` (v5.3.0) emits](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A//+%23if+0%0A%23if+!!defined(__OPTIMIZE__)%0A//+Making+your+code+compile+differently+with/without+optimization+is+a+TERRIBLE+idea%0A//+great+way+to+create+Heisenbugs+that+disappear+when+you+try+to+debug+them.%0A//+Even+if+you+*plan*+to+always+use+-Og+for+debugging,+instead+of+-O0,+this+is+still+evil%0A++%23define+USE_MOVQ%0A%23endif%0A%0A%23define+USE_MOVQ++++//+comment+this+to+let+the+evil+%23ifndef+have+an+effect%0A//%23undef+USE_MOVQ%0A%0A%0A__m256+load_bytes_to_m256(uint8_t+*p)%0A%7B%0A%23ifdef++USE_MOVQ++//+compiles+to+an+actual+movq+then+movzx+ymm,xmm+with+gcc8.3+-O3%0A++++__m128i+small_load+%3D+_mm_loadl_epi64(+(const+__m128i*)p)%3B%0A%23else++//+USE_LOADU+//+compiles+to+a+128b+load+with+gcc+-O0,+potentially+segfaulting%0A++++__m128i+small_load+%3D+_mm_loadu_si128(+(const+__m128i*)p+)%3B%0A%23endif%0A++%0A++++__m256i+intvec+%3D+_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(+small_load+)%3B%0A++++//__m256i+intvec+%3D+_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(+*(__m128i*)p+)%3B++//+compiles+to+an+aligned+load+with+-O0%0A++++return+_mm256_cvtepi32_ps(intvec)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.31960142338032,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g530,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+5.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.34706524328636,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_14_x64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x64+msvc+v19.14+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:31.34706524328636,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang391,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+3.9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',m:62.5,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc1301,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+13.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:37.5,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  (So does MSVC)

```
load_bytes_to_m256(unsigned char*):
        vmovq   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        vpmovzxbd       ymm0, xmm0
        vcvtdq2ps       ymm0, ymm0
        ret
```

The stupid `vmovq` is what we want to avoid.   If you let it use the unsafe `loadu_si128` version, it will make good optimized code.

GCC9, clang, and ICC emit:

```
load_bytes_to_m256(unsigned char*): 
        vpmovzxbd       ymm0, qword ptr [rdi] # ymm0 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,mem[4],zero,zero,zero,mem[5],zero,zero,zero,mem[6],zero,zero,zero,mem[7],zero,zero,zero
        vcvtdq2ps       ymm0, ymm0
        ret
```

---

Writing the AVX1-only version with intrinsics is left as an un-fun exercise for the reader.  You asked for "instructions", not "intrinsics", and this is one place where there's a gap in the intrinsics.  Having to use `_mm_cvtsi64_si128` to avoid potentially loading from out-of-bounds addresses is stupid, IMO.  I want to be able to think of intrinsics in terms of the instructions they map to, with the load/store intrinsics as informing the compiler about alignment guarantees or lack thereof.  Having to use the intrinsic for an instruction I don't want is pretty dumb.

---

Also note that if you're looking in the Intel insn ref manual, there are two separate entries for movq:

- movd/movq, the version that can have an integer register as a src/dest operand (`66 REX.W 0F 6E` (or `VEX.128.66.0F.W1 6E`) for (V)MOVQ xmm, r/m64).  That's where you'll find the intrinsic that can accept a 64-bit integer, `_mm_cvtsi64_si128`.  (Some compilers don't define it in 32-bit mode.)
- movq: the version that can have two xmm registers as operands.  This one is an extension of the MMXreg -> MMXreg instruction, which can also load/store, like MOVDQU.  Its opcode `F3 0F 7E` (`VEX.128.F3.0F.WIG 7E`) for `MOVQ xmm, xmm/m64)`.

  The asm ISA ref manual only lists the `m128i _mm_mov_epi64(__m128i a)` intrinsic for zeroing the high 64b of a vector while copying it.  But [the intrinsics guide does list **`_mm_loadl_epi64(__m128i const* mem_addr)`**](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,Other&expand=6150,6150,401,2424,4728,2796,3388,3388,3324&text=movq) which has a stupid prototype (pointer to a 16-byte `__m128i` type when it really only loads 8 bytes).  It is available on all 4 of the major x86 compilers, and should actually be safe.  Note that the `__m128i*` is just passed to this opaque intrinsic, *not* actually dereferenced.

  The more sane `_mm_loadu_si64 (void const* mem_addr)` is also listed, but gcc is missing that one.

Comment: I tried it with AVX2 based on the comment you referenced in VS2015, with `__m256i m = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32 ((__m128i)(new_image + x));` It wouldn't compile. Looking at the [intel intrinsics page](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) the instruction requires __m128i specifically. Is there a reason to believe that a cast of the kind I've tried would work? I've noticed that VPMOVZXBD does take a memory operand so it's strange that an instrinsic wouldn't.

Comment: @pseudomarvin: note the `*` dereference operator before the cast.  You're missing that, so you're passing a pointer to `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`, not a `__m128i`.  Also, I'd recommend using a `_mm_loadu_si128` so your code is less likely to crash when compiled with `-O0`.  If you want code that still definitely won't access outside the array bounds, even with `-O0`, you have to use `_mm_cvtsi64_si128`, but like my gcc bug report is about, then the load won't fold into a memory operand for `pmovzxbd`.  You're right that it's strange and a bad design for intrinsics.