# How to compare two char vectors using SIMD and store the result as floats?

Tags: c++, c, simd

**GOAL:** identify intrinsics to convert 4 boolean "uint8_t" using a minimum number of aritmetic oeprations, ie, each{mask1 AND mask2}.

**UPDATE:** In order to optimize the code, I'm using SIMD in C++. In contrast to [Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f/34280492#34280492) goal is to handle/support masks for massive arrays. The latter is examplified using 'internal' mask-properties ("https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=10,13"):

```
  uint8_t mask1[4] = {0, 1, 1, 0};  uint8_t mask2[4] = {1, 1, 0, 0}; float data[4] = {5, 4, 2, 1};
  { //! Naive code which works:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if(mask1[i] && mask2[i]) {sum += data[i];}
    }
  }
```

From above we observe the use of masks combiend with simple arithmetic: though the above set of operations is supported by optimized arithmetic, the 'internals' have several weaknesses': (a) constraints the number of operations and (b) place requirements on updated compilers (which is not always the case).

**CONTEXT:**
Challenge concerns the conversion from the "char" data-type to "float" data-type. In order to demonstrate the error in my code, here's a short extract:

```
//! Setup, a setup which is wrong as mask1 and mask2 are chars and not floats.
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>                                                               

char mask1[4] = {0, 1, 0, 1};
char mask2[4] = {1, 0, 0, 1};
const int j = 0;

//! The logics, which is expected to work correct for flroats, ie, not chars.
const __m128 vec_empty_empty = _mm_set1_ps(0);              
const __m128 vec_empty_ones = _mm_set1_ps(1);
const __m128 term1  = _mm_load_ps(&rmul1[j2]); 
const __m128 term2  = mm_load_ps(&rmul2[j2]);
__m128 vec_cmp_1 = _mm_cmplt_ps(term1, vec_empty_empty); 
__m128 vec_cmp_2 = _mm_cmplt_ps(term2, vec_empty_empty); 

//! Intersect the values: included to allow other 'empty values' than '1'.
vec_cmp_1 =  _mm_and_ps(vec_cmp_1, vec_empty_ones);
vec_cmp_2 = _mm_and_ps(vec_cmp_2, vec_empty_ones);

//! Seperately for each 'cell' find the '1's which are in both:
__m128 mask = _mm_and_ps(vec_cmp_1, vec_cmp_2);
```

The result of above is to be used to intersect (ie, multiply) a float vector `float arr[4]`. Therefore, if someone do have any suggestions for how to convert a SIMD char vector into a float SIMD vector, I'd be more than thankful! ;)

Comment: Could you provide a non-simd [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including in- and expected outputs, of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading 8 chars from memory into an \_\_m256 variable as packed single precision floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f)

Comment: thanks for the answers: wrt. @Pixelchemist I have now made the answer more detailed.

Comment: Wrt. suggestion by @PeterCordes the referred-to suggestion only desccribe scalar operations, ie, does not cover the use of vector-based optimizations: in brief, the suggestion results in a more than 2x performance-dealy  (when compared to the non-masked laternative).

Comment: Ok, that's a different question from what I though.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use SSE4.1 `pmovsxbd` or `pmovzxbd` to sign or zero extend a block of 4 bytes to a 16B vector of 32bit integer elements.

Note that [using `pmovzxbd` (`_mm_cvtepu8_epi32`) as a load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280492/224132) seems to be impossible to write both safely and efficiently, because there isn't an intrinsic with a narrower memory operand.  (Update: Some modern compilers are able to fold a narrow load like `_mm_loadu_si32` into a memory source operand for `pmovzx`, e.g. clang but not GCC: https://godbolt.org/z/KPxboPecr)

To do the comparison part, use `pcmpeqd` to generate a mask of all-zero or all-one bits in elements (i.e. `-1`).  Use that to mask the vector of FP data.  (all-zeros is the bit representation of `0.0` in IEEE floats, and 0.0 is the additive identity.)

---

If your elements are always just 0 or 1, you could use a `uint32_t` to hold all four bytes and use a scalar AND (C's `&` operator) as a SWAR implementation of all four `mask1[i] && mask2[i]` checks.  Get that integer into a vector and `pmovsxbd`.  This would work better if your elements were actually 0 and -1 (all-ones), otherwise you need an extra step to get a vector mask.  (e.g. pcmpeqb against and all-zero vector).

If you can't use `-1` instead of `1`, then your best bet is probably to still unpack both masks to 32bit elements and `pcmpeqd`.

The general idea is:

```
          // mask1 = _mm_loadu_si32(something)  // movd load if necessary
__m128i m1vec = _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(mask1);         // where mask1 has to be a __m128i vector already, not a 4byte memory location.
__m128i m2vec = _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(mask2);         // pmovsx

// sign-extension turns each 0 or -1 byte into a 0 or -1 dword (32bit) element

__m128i mask = _mm_and_si128(mask1, mask2);
// convert from 0/1 to 0/-1 if necessary.  I'm assuming the simple case.

__m128 masked_floats = _mm_and_ps(floats, _mm_castsi128_ps(mask));   // 0.0 or original value

sum = _mm_add_ps(sum, masked_floats);
```

If mask elements can be something other than 0 / -1, you might need to booleanize them each separately with `_mm_cmpeq_epi32(m1vec, _mm_setzero_si128())` or something.  (That turns non-zeros into zero and vice versa)

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links, esp. https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/