# GCC w/ inline assembly & -Ofast generating extra code for memory operand

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

I am inputting the address of an index into a table into an extended inline assembly operation, but GCC is producing an extra `lea` instruction when it is not necessary, even when using `-Ofast -fomit-frame-pointer` or `-Os -f...`. GCC is using RIP-relative addresses.

I was creating a function for converting two consecutive bits into a two-part XMM mask (1 quadword mask per bit). To do this, I am using `_mm_cvtepi8_epi64` (internally `vpmovsxbq`) with a memory operand from a 8-byte table with the bits as index.

When I use the intrinsic, GCC produces the exactly same code as using the extended inline assembly.

I can directly embed the memory operation into the ASM template, but that would force RIP-relative addressing always (and I don't like forcing myself into workarounds).

```cpp
typedef uint64_t xmm2q __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

// Used for converting 2 consecutive bits (as index) into a 2-elem XMM mask (pmovsxbq)
static const uint16_t MASK_TABLE[4] = { 0x0000, 0x0080, 0x8000, 0x8080 };

xmm2q mask2b(uint64_t mask) {
    assert(mask < 4);
    #ifdef USE_ASM
        xmm2q result;
        asm("vpmovsxbq %1, %0" : "=x" (result) : "m" (MASK_TABLE[mask]));
        return result;
    #else
        // bad cast (UB?), but input should be `uint16_t*` anyways
        return (xmm2q) _mm_cvtepi8_epi64(*((__m128i*) &MASK_TABLE[mask]));
    #endif
}
```

Output assembly with `-S` (with `USE_ASM` and without):

```
__Z6mask2by:                            ## @_Z6mask2by
        .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
        leaq    __ZL10MASK_TABLE(%rip), %rax
        vpmovsxbq       (%rax,%rdi,2), %xmm0
        retq
        .cfi_endproc
```

What I was expecting (I've removed all the extra stuff):

```
__Z6mask2by:
        vpmovsxbq __ZL10MASK_TABLE(%rip,%rdi,2), %xmm0
        retq
```

Comment: What GCC version do you use. Check [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TBCgF4)

Comment: @VictorGubin: Godbolt GCC is configured with non-PIE as the default.  The OP is clearly using a GCC configured with `--enable-default-pie`.  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)&lq=1

Comment: In any case, I'm on a Macbook Pro with GCC version `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)`. Oh crap, it's just Clang in disguise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only RIP-relative addressing mode is `RIP + rel32`.  **RIP + reg is not available.**

(In machine code, 32-bit code used to have 2 redundant ways to encode `[disp32]`.  x86-64 uses the shorter (no SIB) form as RIP relative, the longer SIB form as `[sign_extended_disp32]`).

---

If you compile for Linux with `-fno-pie -no-pie`, GCC will be able to access static data with a 32-bit absolute address, so it can use a mode like `__ZL10MASK_TABLE(,%rdi,2)`.  This isn't possible for MacOS, where the base address is always above 2^32; 32-bit absolute addressing is completely unsupported on x86-64 MacOS.

In a PIE executable (or PIC code in general like a library), you need a RIP-relative LEA to set up for indexing a static array.  Or any other case where the static address won't fit in 32 bits and/or isn't a link-time constant.

---

#### Intrinsics

Yes, intrinsics make it very inconvenient to express a `pmovzx/sx` load from a narrow source because pointer-source versions of the intrinsics are missing.

`*((__m128i*) &MASK_TABLE[mask]` isn't safe: if you disable optimization, you might well get a `movdqa` 16-byte load but the address will be misaligned.  It's only safe when the compiler folds the load into a memory operand for `pmovzxbq` which has a 2-byte memory operand therefore not requiring alignment.

In fact current GCC *does* compile your code with a `movdqa` 16-byte load like `movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax+rdi*2]` before a reg-reg `pmovzx`.  This is obviously a missed optimization. :(  clang/LLVM (which MacOS installs as `gcc`) does fold the load into `pmovzx`.

The safe way is `_mm_cvtepi8_epi64( _mm_cvtsi32_si128(MASK_TABLE[mask]) )` or something, and then hoping the compiler optimizes away the zero-extend from 2 to 4 bytes and folds the `movd` into a load when you enable optimization.  Or maybe try `_mm_loadu_si32` for a 32-bit load even though you really want 16.  But last time I tried, compilers sucked at folding a 64-bit load intrinsic into a memory operand for `pmovzxbw` for example.  GCC and clang still fail at it, but ICC19 succeeds.  https://godbolt.org/z/IdgoKV

I've written about this before:

- [Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f)
- [How to merge a scalar into a vector without the compiler wasting an instruction zeroing upper elements? Design limitation in Intel's intrinsics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)

---

#### Your integer -> vector strategy

Your choice of `pmovsx` seems odd.  You don't need sign-extension, so I would have picked `pmovzx` (`_mm_cvt_epu8_epi64`).  It's not actually more efficient on any CPUs, though.

A lookup table does work here with only a small amount of static data needed.  If your mask range was any bigger, you'd maybe want to look into 
[is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488675/is-there-an-inverse-instruction-to-the-movemask-instruction-in-intel-avx2) for alternative strategies like broadcast + AND + (shift or compare).

If you do this often, using a whole cache line of 4x 16-byte vector constants might be best so you don't need a `pmovzx` instruction, just index into an aligned table of `xmm2` or `__m128i` vectors which can be a memory source for any other SSE instruction.  Use `alignas(64)` to get all the constants in the same cache line.

You could also consider (intrinsics for) `pdep` + `movd xmm0, eax` + `pmovzxbq` reg-reg if you're targeting Intel CPUs with BMI2.  (`pdep` is slow on AMD, though).

Comment: I need `pmovsx` so that the sign bits are set for both quadwords so that I can perform AVX2 blends (`vblendvpd`) later. When I said masks, I meant _sign_ masks. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @AravK.: The example in your question is sign-extending `0x01` to `0x0000000000000001`.  Did you mean to use `0xFF` -> `0xFFFFFF...`?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the memory addressing! I had believed that _any_ register could be used in the `offset(base,index,scale)` form.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out! I didn't realize that I had set the low bits. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Also: Any chance that GCC can optimize away the `pmovsxbq` and modify the table to use expanded constants (given that it is `static const`)? Or is that too much?

Comment: @AravK.: RIP doesn't really count as a register.  The `offset(%rip)` syntax is basically separate from `offset(base,idx,scale)` with GP registers.

Comment: @AravK.: GCC could in theory optimize your intrinsics source to a table of 4x 16-byte vectors, but in practice I don't think it looks for that transformation.  If you want that, you should simply write it that way in your source with a statically-initialized array of `alignas(64) static const xmm2 masks[] = { {0,0}, {0,-1ULL}, ...};`

Comment: I was wondering about how well GCC can optimize; I would have done it myself. Note that GCC cannot optimize away the 32 -> 128 -> `pmovsx` safe form - it leaves a `vmovd` behind (in `-Ofast`). I'm sticking with the inline assembly version.

Comment: @AravK.: There's a balance between how much and what kind of transformations are reasonable.  Like if you wrote an InsertionSort, would you want the compiler to *always* replace it with a QuickSort?  Even moreso for changing the size vs. speed tradeoff from the source by using fewer or cheaper instructions but a larger table.  That's very different from the missed optimization of not folding a `vmovd` load into a memory source for `vpmovsx`.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to let you know about the `vmovd` (and not relate it to the table optimization). I agree completely.