# Converting assembly code to intrinsic code?

Tags: assembly, simd, intrinsics, avx512

I have code in assembly which takes single floats, stores them in zmm registers. Then, it loads them, makes them into 32bit integers.

```
"vbroadcastss (%0), %%zmm2\n\t" 
"vbroadcastss (%1), %%zmm1\n\t"
"vpmovzxbd (%2,%3), %%zmm0\n\t"
```

I want to convert this into intrinsics using this:

```
 __m512 _mm512_broadcastss_ps (__m128 a)
```

and

```
__m512i _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i a)
```

I'm not sure how to use registers in intrinsics. How can I express (%0), (%1), (%2) elements in intrinsics?

Comment: Try `_mm512_set1_ps()` for the broadcasts.  As for the third one, what are `%2` and `%3`?  Possibly, you need a `_mm_loadu_si128` to load the operand from memory first.

Comment: There are no memory-source intrinsics for `pmovzx`; it's up to the compiler to fold a load into the `__m128i` source operand.  This often works when it's a 128-bit load, but most compilers fail at it when it's only a 64-bit or 32-bit load, emitting a braindead `vmovd` + `vpmovzx` sequence or whatever.  [Loading 8 chars from memory into an \_\_m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34279513) / [and this](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496)