# SIMD (AVX2) - load uint8_t values to multiple float __m256 registers

Tags: simd, avx2

I have grayscale image from `uint8_t` values. I want to load data to SIMD. I load 16 values and convert them to two `__m256` float registers.

I use:

```
uint8_t * data = .....
size_t index = ....

//load 16 uint8_t (16 * 8 = 128bit)
__m128i val = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(data + index));

//convert to 16bit int
__m128i lo16 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(val, _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i hi16 = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(val, _mm_setzero_si128());

//convert to 32bit int
__m256i lo32 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(lo16);
__m256i hi32 = _mm256_cvtepi16_epi32(hi16);

//convert to float
__m256 lo = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(lo32);
__m256 hi = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(hi32);
```

Is there a better way how to do this (without AVX-512), than my solution?

Would it be better to load `_mm256_loadu_si256` and "split" it to 4 `__m256` registers?

Answer (score 2):

It would cost even more shuffles to unpack the high lane of a `_mm256_loadu_si256`.  Most AVX2 CPUs have more load throughput than shuffle throughput, and you already need at least 1 shuffle per output vector, so already your way of doing 1 load and 4 shuffles for 2 `epi32` vectors is a poor tradeoff.

If anything it would be better to use 2x `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32` to get two vectors of inputs to cvtepi32_ps, with one load per shuffle.

It's a bit of a pain to use memory-source `pmovz/sx` because you need to tell the compiler you're doing a narrow load into a `__m128i` (for safety), and some compilers won't optimize away the zero-extending load into a memory-source for `vpmovzx`.  **See [Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f)**

But apparently things have improved some since I originally wrote that answer in 2015; GCC9 and later fixed that missed-optimization bug and now folds a `_mm_loadl_epi64( (const __m128i*)p)` into a memory source for `vpmovzx`.  clang and ICC are fine, even old versions.  MSVC still does poor code-gen with a separate `vmovq`, even with `-march:AVX2`, even v19.28 and "latest".  ([Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ1QBXYsg4ByKQGY8tZK2VYA1OO0BhPAFsregsT0A6BGeziADAEEdeg0cymFgoE%2BPTOrh7eXgD00aaSulTG7pE%2BSWBgWFR6mOgQAPr5APIACgAqAJIAshUAWtiFAJSRscZVzADWesDGAJ4qxMZoJmhWAA547Mb4VFSYxJj0rL3GAO6ECNHrBAgqBMaoYwTWeABezMd0xngKxszGZdgASk8V0gAy2NdYzC1xwAsLmtmCsiENAQQAgAJTA3RYAI2UwFuOyB%2BAUzDGY0wzEGqwQiz6KmM9lBqGmmERPR2mCsjj%2BxmwADdCXgkv1lMYAFRjYS0Lkk8lsVYg27KBQBAC0RR6NEGWCpwG6pGutGCOPQByS0vcKp2N2ut2Ck1YxkwTMmkWM8W0WRyxgAqgwGlUigA1ACKqQSixmqS8OjttACTpd7o91utrVGVkW%2B31KPJ7HjBLNFtNaVoWWMCGYLLutDNs0wyAIfx0yizmCSofyrs9/qinkKVkkAFYAGzGVioZjofLw3qQhT5Ij5VudiDKOwADlH3LGzQDAHZZAGEmzs47nXXw1G4qMJuxEwW7qXlGxjFZUEyAI4kgmF69M04ADz6NlIr5saw2xmAyDIDOjjaMY0raFakYtpwkgzngxgKFYbCsPkPZ9oEAAixjjlYqG9ugKGYBMHbcBAxgQGgar7NBsF4FyjSLmYa7eD6rASvu24NO8RSeBhDrGNGqDjJMmAnvcMEzvC3b4b%2BOz/oBYFFLqxhjKgkL0HgyErBKwBUMwyisMcoiQdaNFwQhSGsChaGamYWE4XhfbKPkCh4BJZEUXQwTYeOEl0QxxjNNozE6L6bKQSZPkTh28F2CyyCYdhNjth2%2BTIEykJjMoc5EXg2iSGRiHIY5mpBcxkYCdELYpbF9DxYlOEpWlGVEdl%2BS5flZFcgUvm0fRYyBUxHGHiJYmFmweDAMGmo2bJCCKSkXgVQsBCqIWjWds1mV5ZI%2BRjAoEBxSWZWpMuGGRBojRCCAGhthopC0Dd7j3agN3mHIcgIQM6g2pw90EE9l1XR0IDaG2IGcAAnB27g8Ak2gzu4%2BXXRo3D3Y9GjPaQr0aPdCggLqAOY5dpBwLAMCICgQlHvM5CUCN7DECAwCQ9opDZIZ8z4xA8KA6Q8J6LivQ3X9pAxnGRS0MsfNYEhojsDLeALKWeAsvjxOkJgr4lsokIi/ddiYKwfOsHg8LEEL5gYJoov2NY%2BtXTQ9BMGwHA8Pwgh8mIH0yEIZv45AV2HJcao3ZKADqyGKaBkpIWoLjaBhuYKKsRusHjRsliHlC%2BlbhhWI9nCa1m7w5AAcsoVjwvMgiqa5Id55XhekHXhB4HQpfBhXVc10XErsCrdAMAQuIEI3BeCP3Wft7Qw%2Bj53mDd9XTN9yPxBj6g%2BfN8E8/l5Xy9cFdSiqOoh8o3dD18zjr4zh2kokfJCWQyB5G4IQJC/SqVvCYzv2NMY70ZByH%2BoDRowNQacBAtwZc7gOxtkkNwfKt9tAdhRmjUgVgQBtl1BjLGOM8YE1IETZ6V0yaUwZrTCgnkf41w0EyZAWJ8hMihvkWC%2BQIBugYJwVKkNGj5FfCRe6HNITEG5rzDWAtaBC31mLISsZ6CS2lhrWWIhgAK2UUraeas%2BZax1nrDQotDbGw1qbc2ltrYyLtpggxJMnaMBYArd2AhJBCFUSgH28hTEBwgEHI4M91bSkkGBXEyAkCeDdAADUkBnAe2cIC503k3QQvoF5L17i3VA9cZ7j2bq3EOqT97pKnoPWea8N5b0npnEpc914FJ7ivRQZScmTzKXUg%2BnAj7fTdldYxF9cEvRugI7gV4FD0OMMw5%2BsFyKcO4Y4Xhr98BEEGDoIuADqYiWWQkSQ/9AGyBkCA4mYDSAEj7DXHxaD7qYOwZfDW%2BDFCEOIUDUgINtCQO0NA2B8DEGwQ7CglG2h0ZXxugckhpMKZkIgEgChZAqHQpQF7bQkMi7CK5pQcRWNJHSJsbImwEspbC2UbSVR6isb4GVscbRGtdHIF1jbA29AjYmzNhbYgvQrZYEsQ4axf1HZ0Hsa7LgvABBsy9u4oBvsvHwF8SHAJkcrLRzAnHUJdlk6pysjE6edAc5ZmaUXFJe96m10yW3OguqMlZI7ga9pigqkhxqeUpJfdbUz3tW0opTTEkT1XrvLuhSV6dJPt08%2BgLbmDNvvfYZBhVHGG0HMxwnAFnv02a8r%2B6zf46G0DsjxIKnkvNjdoAthai1FouRgkAHZJCODbDcvBwL7mE1AWC%2BAkKqY0JhfTNNNc8CAU4NoWG7NJgiLEXzTFrKZHiwUfimWRL5aaFJZolWlKsbUtpTIoxTKzGsvZXSohXKHbsz5S7RxQqQC8FFRIcVnj/ZSuxn4ryYc5WmnAoqkJCck7MBTmnDVJTtXoDNfq31hqi55OyZ63Jxr8lWqKc6oeHqKlOtiS61pUGGk73XmatDBA3X%2BsUF0s%2BvSQ21o0DfO%2BD9u0JV7Y4dw8bE1LM/msttNpuBZsvTmo5JysBM3OcY9BmDtDLirTWgZuN61ENAeAgtIFi3SYLf8wjwm2M9JutEoT2M62PKOSyURM9T1AA)).

---

On Intel CPUs `vpmovzxbd ymm, qword [mem]` is always 2 uops; can't micro-fuse the load (only for an xmm destination) https://uops.info/table.html, so you don't gain anything (except code-size) even if the compiler does manage to fold a 64-bit memory source into a mem operand instead of using a `vmovq` load.

But on Zen2, that instruction has 2/clock throughput, vs. worse than 1/clock throughput for `vpmovzxbd ymm, xmm` (same for the `wd` shuffle, or the sign-extending version you're using, [vpmovsxwd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovsx) = epi16_epi32).  So you do really want the compiler to get this right if you care about Zen CPUs, especially Zen 2.