# Compact storage of shuffle vectors: unpacking 4 bytes to shuffle uint32_t elements with a byte-shuffle

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, neon

I have a cross architecture code that looks up a shuffle by index, for moving `uint32_t` elements within a vector. A whole vector constant is needed for each shuffle, but there are only 4 bytes of non-redundant information.  (Or really 4x 2 bits of information, but that would be more expensive to unpack.)

On SSSE3-SSE4.2 I use `_mm_shuffle_epi8` and on arm it's `table` intrinsics.

---

However, right now I store the whole shuffle mask, aka control vector, so for example for identity for `int` I will store:
`0x0f0e0d0c0b0a09080706050403020100`

I would like to just store `0x03020100`, with each unique shuffle control element stored in a single byte / `uint8_t`.

Is there an efficient way to get from one to the other?
convert + multiply seems a bit heavy.

Comment: What about just a lookup table of control vectors?  Then you can easily encode your permutation as packed 8 bits and use it as an index into an array of 256 control vectors (most unused).  Or encode it even more compactly if you want - there are only 24 possible permutations.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The original question didn't imply that it was a permutation, e.g. never getting 2 copies of one element and dropping another.  I added the "moving around" phrase when trying to reword to introduce what this was about earlier in the question.  Anyway, 256 x 16 B = 4 KiB.  That's still a pretty hefty footprint, a decent fraction of L1d$.  Depending on the use-case, it might be worth it (e.g. in a loop), but for occasional calls a compact table is more likely to hit in cache, and maybe worth the extra cost of loading two fixed vectors and running an extra pshufb+paddb.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I guess you had in mind when you need the same shuffle for multiple LUT entries that you're looking up based on a concatenation of multiple `_mm_movemask_ps` results or something; yeah that makes sense.

Comment: They are permutations, and there only 9 of them. At the moment I do exactly that a LUT of 9 elements of complete bytes.

However: 
1: cannot reuse the same table for different types, 2: it would be nice to shrink the table for the sake of smaller table.

Answer (score 3):

**Store your packed LUT with each byte holding the starting byte number, so you don't need to scale them up.**
Broadcast each control index into the bytes of the corresponding element (1 fixed shuffle), then add a constant `set1_epi32(0x03020100)` to offset them.

```
  __m128i v = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(shuffle_lut[i]);

  v = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v, _mm_set1_epi32(0x03030303, 0x02020202, 0x01010101, 0x00000000));  // broadcast each byte into a dword
  v = _mm_add_epi8(v, _mm_set1_epi32(0x03020100));   // offset the byte indices

 // v is your shuffle-control vector, usable with another pshufb
 // as if you'd just unpacked lut[i]>>2 to dwords for vpermilps
```

The identity shuffle is stored as `0x0c080400`.  0x0c + 0x03 = 0x0f in the top byte of the top element.

I guess your LUT in C is actually done as `uint32_t shuffle_lut`, in which case you don't have to worry about doing strict-aliasing-safe dword loads.  Intrinsics support for that is dicey, but `_mm_cvtsi32_si128` for `movd` is easy to use.  It takes a value (not an address), so in C terms the memory access happens in pure C.  The compiler can still fold the load into a memory operand for `movd` though.

---

BTW, I assume you said up to SSE4.2 because AVX1 has `_mm_permutevar_ps` ([`vpermilps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps)), so a `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32` (`pmovzxbd`) can unpack a 4-byte load for that without further modification.  Using dword indices, not byte indices, so you *would* store the identity shuffle as `0x03020100` for this.

Unfortunately getting the compiler to emit a memory-source `vpmovzxbd xmm0, [rdi]` instruction from intrinsics code is a pain with compilers other than clang.  They often fail to fold the `movd` or `movq` load intrinsic into a memory source operand, but you have to use that not a full `__m128i` load if you don't want to go past the end of a buffer in a debug build.  See [Loading 8 chars from memory into an __m256 variable as packed single precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279513/loading-8-chars-from-memory-into-an-m256-variable-as-packed-single-precision-f) for actual compiler results a few years ago.

---

### AVX2 or BMI2+AVX packing into a single byte

There are really only 2 bits of information per shuffle index, so four indices can be packed into 1 byte (`uint8_t`).

On way to unpack is with BMI2 integer [`pdep`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep).  i.e.  `_pdep_u32(lut[i], 0x03030303`.  Then `vmovd` / `vpmovzxbd` / `vpermilps`.  Perhaps the `pdep` could even be replaced by a multiplier constant, since `vpermilps` only cares about the low 2 bits of each dword.

But `pext` is very slow on AMD before Zen3.  And even on Intel, that's a significant amount of latency to load into integer first.

Another option is using AVX2 variable-shift to bring the appropriate 2 bits to the bottom of each dword element.  Start with a broadcast load of the byte.  Or more efficiently in most cases (except cache line splits), a dword broadcast which CPUs can do "for free" in a load port, no separate ALU shuffle uop needed.  (https://uops.info/)

It's a pain to avoid strict-aliasing UB for that, e.g. `_mm_set1_epi32( *(uint32_t*) &lut[i] )` isn't safe.  But there is an intrinsic that takes a pointer, `_mm_broadcast_ss`.

```
  // make sure LUT[] doesn't end right at the end of a page
  // so we can broadcast-load 4 bytes starting at any byte offset in it.
  // i.e. pad it by 3 bytes if needed.
  __m128i v = _mm_castps_si128( _mm_broadcast_ss( (const float*)&LUT[i] ));

  // alternative:  __m128i v = _mm_set1_epi8( LUT[i] );  // vpbroadcastb is an extra shuffle uop, but narrower load

  v = _mm_srlv_epi32(v, _mm_set_epi32(6, 4, 2, 0));

  // ready for _mm_permutevar_ps
 // low 2 bits of each 32-bit element of v are correct
```

It's not necessary to `_mm_and_si128`; [`vpermilps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermilps) doesn't care about high garbage in the control vector elements.

Note that there's no XMM version of AVX2 `vpermd`, so even with AVX2 available, `vpermilps` is still the best choice of variable-control shuffle which uses 32-bit granularity.

(Unless you want to widen your whole algorithm to 8 elements in a `__m256i`, then yeah use lane-crossing `vpermd` aka `_mm256_permutexvar_epi32`.  But then you need 8 x 3 bits of shuffle-control data = 3 bytes not 1.  And then there are probably still too many possibilities to make a LUT for.)

Also related:

- [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask) generating shuffle vectors on the fly instead of looking them up, because the LUT would have to be too big for 8-element vectors.
- [Fastest way to get IPv4 address from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679341/fastest-way-to-get-ipv4-address-from-string#comment51380552_31683632) compresses a LUT of shuffle control vectors by processing an `_mm_movemask_epi8` result instead of using it directly to index 65536 x `__m128i` (1MiB) table of shuffle vectors.